# latex elongated parentheses

Tags: latex

How to make the first matrix look like the latter?

[image]

The code of the first matrix is:

```
$$F(x)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{x}{2} & 0 \\
0 & x^2\\
\end{array}\right)$$
```

Comment: I hope you can't. If someone introduced these abominations to LaTeX, it'll be a huge disappointment to me.

Comment: one does not normally elaborate on a joke, but if you insist -- these Equation-Editor-style parentheses are ugly. You can even see how the three parts they are made of do not fit together all that well where they meet. Knuth created TeX to make sure that his books are beautiful -- at least that was his initial motivation.

Comment: @AB: Both are ugly: the Tex example has too little space separating the items in the first column (the contrast with the space in the second column is painful), whilst the use of the same font size for the fraction as the other sizes is really ugly. I should think that Knuth uses diagonal slashes rather than atop to typeset fractions in matrices - who wants to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second (wanted) example uses a different math font family. These define the thin brackets. I'm not a font expert, so I can't tell you which font this example uses.
I can tell you, I know the Math-Fourier font also uses thin brackets. This is what I've used to recreate your second example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{fourier} % The Math font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\[
F(x)={\scriptstyle \left(\begin{array}{cc}
{\textstyle \frac{x}{2}} & {\displaystyle 0}\\
\vphantom{{\displaystyle W}} % uses some vertical spacing
                             % between the first and second row
{\displaystyle 0} & {\displaystyle x^{2}}\end{array}\right)}\]

\end{document}
```