# Rounded square brackets

Tags: brackets, parentheses, curly-braces

dear experts!
I am trying to encode rounded square brackets in LaTeX. "**[ ]**" are not suitable because not rounded, look clumsy, and can be misinterpreted. Round regular brackets "**( )**" are also categorically inappropriate.

There don't seem to be any special brackets, but it is possible to use matrix brackets. See the second case:
[latex elongated parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531181/latex-elongated-parentheses)

But those parentheses look too big. When I write, for example, "***f*[*x*]**" they are terribly huge and with unnecessary spaces. Please help make the brackets!

Comment: The code from "latex elongated parentheses" dosen't work.

Comment: \[      F(x)=F{\scriptstyle \left(\begin{array}{cc}
{x} \end{array}\right)} \]

Comment: Do you have any ideas?